# map condition to true or ignore apping

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I have an "IsActive" field on DTO & Entity.

```
 public class Dto {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public bool IsActive {get;set;}
 }

 public class Entity {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public bool IsActive {get;set;}
 }
```

And I want to map it below

> ```
> * Set value to true if Id == 0
> * Ignore mapping if ID != 0
> ```

How can I do it?

```
        CreateMap<Dto, Entity>(MemberList.Source)
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Active, options => options.Condition((dto, entity) => ??));
```

I have kept `IsActive` in `Dto` as I need it to pass it to the client.

Comment: `public bool IsActive => Id == 0;` ?

Comment: Much quicker would be to map it manually :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CreateMap<Dto, Entity>(MemberList.Source).ForMember(dto => dto.Active, options => options.Condition((dto, entity) => entity.Id==0 ? true : entity.Active));
```

Answer (score 1):

finally this is what I got

```
            .ForMember(entity => entity.Active, options => options.MapFrom((dto, entity) => dto.Id == 0 ? true : entity.Active))
```